# Django REST Serializer, show an exact value

Tags: python, django, rest

Really I did an almost 5-hours research and could not find something that will work the way I want.

The question is just a simple one, I suppose. I wanna build a REST Django framework for Game, with serializers etc.

When I try to ask for "Genres"(Game Genres), the JSON return this:
[Genre Serializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix5Jf.png)

Ideally, I just want to return only the values of the game genres without the annoying "GenreTitle", everywhere.

My model:

```
class Genre(models.Model):
   GenreTitle = models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name = 'Title')
   GenreDescription = models.TextField(max_length=500,verbose_name = 'Description')
   GenreImage = models.ImageField(null=True, verbose_name='Image')

def __str__(self):
    return self.GenreTitle
```

My serializer:

```
class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model= Genre
       fields=('GenreTitle',)
```

I know that is a pice of cake for Django developers, but i struggle much because I am beginner at this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is already beautifully documented in [django rest docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include)

You just need to include needed fields, If you want all fields just do so:

```
class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = '__all__'
```

If you need everything without *annoying* `GenreTitle` then exclude it

```
class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        exclude = ('GenreTitle',)
```

If you want specifics:

```
class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ('GenreTitle', 'GenreDescription', 'GenreImage')
```

Comment: I think that my question wasn't clear after all, sorry for this.
Again, I just wanted the data only like, "Action,Platform,Adventure" etc.
instead of "GenreTitle:Action,GenreTitle:Platform,GenreTitle:Adventure"

Comment: Then you don't need django rest serializer for that. You just need to `return Response(Genre.objects.values_list('GenreTitle', flat=True))` in your view and that's all.

Comment: I am sure that I am the reason that you can' understand my question :P
Maybe this could make it more clear why I want to do this.
This is what I want to achieve: https://ibb.co/h7rzBQ

Comment: Now i got you. But unfortunately i don't think that this is achievable. The workaround would be to make `GameGenre` as `serializers.MethodField()` and then write method `.get_GameGenre(self, obj)` to return your desired list.

Comment: Thanks a million for your time and your help :)